# Copy Constructor for MyString causes HEAP error. Only Gives Error in Debug Mode

Tags: visual-c++

So, I've never experienced this before.  Normally when I get an error, it always triggers a breakpoint.  However, this time when I build the solution and run it without debugging (ctrl+F5), it gives me no error and runs correctly.  But when I try debugging it (F5), it gives me this error:

```
HEAP[MyString.exe]: HEAP: Free Heap block 294bd8 modified at 294c00 after it was freed
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in MyString.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in MyString.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while MyString.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.
```

This assignment is due tonight, so I'd appreciate any quick help.

My code is here:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8d84b21be6d1f4bc18bf

I've narrowed the problem down in the main to line 18 in main.cpp ( c = a + b; )  The concatenation succeeds, but then when it is to be copied into c, the error message occurs at line 56 in MyString.cpp ( pData = new char[length + 1]; ).

The kicker is I haven't had a problem with this line of code until I tried overloading the operator>>.  I've since scrapped that code for the sake of trying to debug this.

Again, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please post the relevant code within your post, not on some other site.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through line 18:

```
1. In line 17 you create string c with dynamically allocated memory inside.
2. You make assignment: c = a + b:
  2.1. Operator+ creates LOCAL object 'cat'.
  2.2. cat's memory is allocated dynamically.
  2.3. cat becomes concatenation of two given strings.
  2.4. Operator+ exits. cat is LOCAL object and it's being destroyed.
    2.4.1. cat is being destroyed. cat's destructor runs.
    2.4.2. destructor deletes pData;
    2.4.3. After delete you make *pData = NULL. //ERROR - should be pData = NULL (1)
  2.5. c is initialized with result of operator+.
  2.6. operator= calls copy().
  2.7. copy() allocates new memory without checking the current one. //ERROR - memory leak (2)
```

**(1)**
pData is char*. In destructor we have: delete[] pData (deletes memory) and then *pData = NULL.
Because pData is a pointer, *pData is same as pData[0]. So you write to already freed memory. This is the cause of your error.

**(2)**
Additional problem. Copy() overwrites current memory without checking. Should be:

```
copy()
{
    if(this->pData)
    {
        delete this->pData;
    }
    //now allocate new buffer and copy
}
```

Also, when dealing with raw bytes (chars), you don't want to use new() and delete(), but malloc() and free() instead. In this case, in functions like copy(), instead of calling delete() and then new(), you would simply use realloc().

EDIT:
One more thing: errors caused by heap damage usually occur during debugging. In release binary, this will simply overwrite some freed (and maybe already used by someone else) memory. That's why debugging is so important when playing with memory in C++.